# Finding the smallest set of integers which contain at least one number that does not share digits with every integer in a second set

Tags: optimization, algorithms

The following problem is in **base 4**.

**n** is the number of base 4 digits within each integer in **Set A** and **Set B**

For each number in a set of integers from **0** to **4<sup>n</sup>-1** (Set A), there must be at least one number in a second set of integers (Set B) with which it does not share any digits (in the same units column). For example, **121 and 023** share a digit but **003 and 321** do not. In other words, if there exists a number in Set A that shares at least one digit with every number in Set B, then Set B is **invalid**.

## Given **n** digits, how can we find the smallest possible Set B?

When **n < 4**, Set B can be determined quite simply as seen below.

**n=2 example**

**Set A:** 00, 01, 02, 03, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 30, 31, 32, 33 *(size: 16)*
**Set B:** 00, 11, 22 *(size: 3)*

**n=3 example**

**Set A:** 000, 001, 002, 003, 010, ..., 333 *(size: 64)*
**Set B:** 000, 111, 222, 333 *(size: 4)*

When **n >= 4**, Set B can become harder to find. The following solutions were found via a genetic algorithm but I am unable to tell if these sets are the smallest possible. Furthermore, such an approach becomes prohibitively slow for significantly larger values of **n**.

**n=4 example**

**Set A:** 0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, 0010, ..., 3333 *(size: 256)*
**Set B:** 0011, 0022, 1100, 2200, 1111, 2222, 3333 *(size: 7)*

**n=5 example**

**Set A:** 00000, 00001, 00002, 00003, 00010, ..., 33333 *(size: 1024)*
**Set B:** 02213, 03112, 03203, 11330, 12301, 20121, 22100, 23212, 30020, 31031 *(size: 10)*